# Uncaught NSException in lemmatization Swift code

Tags: ios, swift, lemmatization

Got this kind of error :

> NSLinguisticTagger
>   enumerateTagsInRange:unit:scheme:options:usingBlock:]: Range or index
>   out of bounds

and not sure what's happening. I passed in the in put "eat a apple" and the error pops up. "eat apple" works fine. "a" is a stop word I filtered. How do I prevent this error from popping up? Here's the error [message(image)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oN-OIE-RzcYnVe-L9Z99h9c5NQmSGbE6/view?usp=sharing)   + `terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

Here's the lemmatization code I used:

`tagger` is `NSLinguisticTagger(tagSchemes: [.tokenType, .language, .lexicalClass, .nameType, .lemma], options: 0)`, `options` is `NSLinguisticTagger.Options = [.omitPunctuation, .omitWhitespace, .joinNames]`

```
func lemmatization(for text: String) {
        let words = text.components(separatedBy: " ")
        let input = words.filter( { !StopWords.stopwords.contains($0) } ).joined(separator: " ")
        tagger.string = input
        print(input)
        let range = NSRange(location:0, length: text.utf16.count)
        tagger.enumerateTags(in: range, unit: .word, scheme: .lemma, options: options) { (tag, tokenRange, stop) in
            do {
                let word = (input as NSString).substring(with: tokenRange)
                if let lemma = tag?.rawValue {
                    print("\(word) -> \(lemma)")
                   // wordList[word] = wordList[word].g
                } else {
                    print("\(word) -> ???")
                }
            } catch {

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `range` should be computed from `input`, not from  `text`

Comment: @Martin R that fixed it!